# Ruby: adding a new element to each array in an array, such that the new element is the downcased version of an existing element

Tags: arrays, ruby

if

```
@users = User.all.group_by(&:iso).map{|k,v| [k, v.count]}
```

returns

```
 [["GB", 1], ["GI", 3], ["BD", 1]]
```

Why can't I do this

```
 @users = User.all.group_by(&:iso).map{|k,v| [k, v.count, k.downcase]}
```

to get

```
[["GB", 1, "gb"], ["GI", 3, "gi"], ["BD", 1, "bd"]]
```

I am getting the error

```
      undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass
```

How do I get this.

If I do

```
   @user_json = User.all.group_by(&:iso).map{|k,v| [k, v.count, k.inspect]}
```

I get

```
   [["GB", 1, "\"GB\""], ["GI", 3, "\"GI\""], ["BD", 1, "\"BD\""]
```

and then

```
  @user_json = User.all.group_by(&:iso).map{|k,v| [k, v.count, k.inspect.downcase]}

 [["GB", 1, "\"gb\""], ["GI", 3, "\"gi\""], ["BD", 1, "\"bd\""]
```

V. confused

FOR MORE DETAILS - THIS WORKS (but if it is wrong and can't explain why)

I am trying to build a JSON array with the structure:

```
   [{"code":"GB","value":1,"flag":"gb"},{"code":"GI","value":3,"flag":"gi"},{"code":"BD","value":1,"flag":"bd"}]
```

My controller code

```
     def global_chart
          @user_json = User.all.group_by(&:iso).map{|k,v| [k, v.count, k.to_s.downcase]}.map {|c, v | ["code" => c, "value" => v, "flag" => c.to_s.downcase]}.flatten.to_json
          render 'users/charts/global'
    end
```

This works ( the @user_json variable has the right structure) however I can't explain the behaviour above....

Comment: why you can't? You can

Comment: I get: undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass

Comment: so one of your 'iso' is empty. try this `User.all.group_by(&:iso).map{|k,v| [k, v.count, k.try(:downcase)]}`

Comment: With your code I get:                                                                     undefined local variable or method `downcase' for #<UsersController:0x007fdab38110b0>

Comment: what will return `k.to_s.downcase`?

Comment: Yep, that works.....make it an answer!

Comment: Actually it is wrong behavior. You should check your code for a fat bug.

Comment: Please explain (many thanks)

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
@users = User.all.group_by(&:iso).map{ |k,v| [k, v.count] }
```

is absolutely valid and its output shows us that you have got only three iso groups. Then

```
@users = User.all.group_by(&:iso).map{ |k,v| [k, v.count, k.downcase] }
```

is absolutely valid code as well. But you get an error `undefined method 'downcase' for nil:NilClass` which tells us that one of iso values is `nil`. Which is not true from your first example output.

After that, your third snippet

```
User.all.group_by(&:iso).map{ |k,v| [k, v.count, k.inspect.downcase] }
```

which is again correct, returns the same output as first one (I mean same sample of iso).

So somewhere in your code is bug. I believe it is close to provided piece of code. You could show whole controller's code to see maybe the problem is on the surface.